# forceChatter:publisher

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to use forceChatter:publisher but I could not, it says

```
No COMPONENT named markup://forceChatter:publisher found : [markup://...]
```

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceChatter:publisher

Should I implement anything to user forceChatter:publisher?

```
<aura:component>
    <forceChatter:publisher context="Record" recordId="XY....Z"/>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post your code to help others reproduce the problem.

Without seeing your code, I would guess that you may be using an older Salesforce version in which this component is not available.

`forceChatter:publisher` is only available from Winter 17 (API version 38), which is not yet live in all instances.

You can find the Winter 17 sandbox release dates on the [Salesforce blog](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/08/salesforce-winter-17-sandbox-preview-instructions.html):

[image]

Comment: updated code, API version of that component is 37.
May be it is not available in my instance yet.

Comment: Ah, that's it then.  Please see updated answer and mark your question as resolved.

Comment: 38 is available now, and code saves fine with forceChatter:publisher. 
But I dont get to see anything ... absolute BLANK.
Also any idea on 'forceChatter:exposedFeed' from link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_forceChatter_publisher.htm
When i try to use I get "No COMPONENT named exposedFeed found".
Thanks for your time.